# How to get greatest or least value in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, greatest-n-per-group

How to get greatest or least value of two columns or some arithmatic done?

Same can be done in MYSQL.

[Greatest in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function%5Fgreatest)

[Least in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)

I don't want MAX and MIN functions. I want comparatively max and min of different values.

I am currently doing it with case? Is there any better option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNWIND` on a collection combined with `MAX` function:

```
UNWIND [1,2,3] AS x
RETURN max(x)
```

Comment: I don't want MAX and MIN. It will check on same column. I mentioned in question clearly. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: Don't quite understand what you want to achieve. Using the `UNWIND/MAX ` combo allows you to find the largest value within an collection.

Comment: I want to max between two collections.

Comment: Isn't the mysql GREATEST in that example also operating on just one collection?

Answer (score 0):

`order by` will not work?

```
MATCH (n)
WITH n, Id(n) as param //now pick up 1 node
ORDER BY param DESC //or ASC
LIMIT 1
MATCH n--x //now continue with querying with the 1 picked node
RETURN n, x
```